# If a process at index 1 is executed from a sempahore's wait queue via signal(), does the process at index 0 also get executed?

Tags: multiprocessing, synchronization, semaphore, blocking, critical-section

I'm new to semaphores, so I am not sure if there are different definitions for **signal()** and **wait()**.  In my textbook, **signal()** is defined as:

```
signal(semaphore *S) {  
    S->value++;  
    if (S->value <= 0) {  
        // remove a process P from S->list;  
        wakeup(P);  
    }  
}
```

and more simply as:

```
signal(S) {    
    S++;    
}
```

and **wait()** is defined as:

```
wait(semaphore *S) {  
    S->value--;  
    if (S->value < 0) {  
        // add this process to S->list;  
        block();  
    }  
}
```

and more simply as:

```
wait(S) {  
    while (S <= 0)  
        ; // busy wait  
    S--;  

}
```

Say you have the following:

> Process 90: wait(s1);
> Process 91: wait(s1);
> Process 95: wait(s1);

This produces the current values of the semaphore as:

```
semaphore s1 {  
    value = -3;  
    *list = { 90, 91, 95};  // processes will be awakened in order from left to right  
}
```

I understand that **wait()** decrements **value** and **signal()** increments **value**.

I believe that if the following sequence is executed (possibly on different cores), this would be what happens.

> Process 101:   signal( s1); --> value = -2
> Process 81:     signal( s1);  --> value = -1
> Process 100:   wait( s1); --> list = {90, 91, 95, 100}
> Process 83:     signal( s1); --> value = -1
> Process 85:     signal( s1); --> value = 0
> Process 103:   signal( s1); --> value = 1, list = {91, 95, 100}
> Process 95:   signal( s1); --> value = 2, list = {100}

1. Since the processes are awakened from the queue from left to right(FIFO), would process 91 also be awakened from the queue when process 95 executes **signal()**? if so, is Process 91 just unblocked and can now be executed at the scheduler's discretion? Or does it affect the value?
2. in the definition of **signal()**, it says if value is <=0, awaken a process. Does this mean when Process 101 is executed, that the list would become **list = {101, 105}**?

Comment: PS. I do not want answers to any of the processes executed in the sequence shown, I am just looking for explanations on how it works because my textbook doesn't explain it with enough detail